# How to create named functions for dynamic key bindings?

Tags: key-bindings, functions

I am creating a keymap based on a configuration file.
The resulting keys all call the same function but with different arguments.
Here is the code I am using for a single key:

```
(defun add-do-my-stuff-keybinding (config-pair)
  "Add config to do-my-stuff-map"
 (define-key do-my-stuff-map (kbd (config-get-key config-pair))
   `(lambda ()
      (interactive)
      (do-stuff ,(config-get-name config-pair)))))
```

My question is, is there a way to avoid the lambda so that the inspection of the keybindings does not show a lambda but a helpful function name?

Something like generating defuns oder named lambdas?

Comment: An alternative approach is to bind all keys in question to the same function. The function could check which key it was executed from and use a suitable "configuration" (whatever that is).

Comment: That could be a solution, yes. I was aiming for something that allows me to execute "Prefix + C-h" to see what the keys themselves do with out inspecting every single. It's more to reduce memorization than anything else.

Comment: I haven't delved into it too much myself, but I would try using `defmacro` to define a macro returning a function generated from the config-file key + pair. The generated function could get a proper name and documentation string (using the `declare` form) and then be used instead of the lambda.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have found a solution. Thanks to [Erik Sjöstrand](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/users/9695/erik-sj%C3%B6strand) for pointing me in the right direction. I was able to find [this stackoverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12714919/2328956).

Simply aliasing the lambda function is enough.

```
(defun add-do-my-stuff-keybinding (config-pair)
  "Add config to do-my-stuff-map"
 (define-key do-my-stuff-map (kbd (config-get-key config-pair))
  (defalias (intern (concat "my-stuff-" (config-get-name config-pair))
  `(lambda ()
    ,(format "Call `do-my-stuff` for %s" (config-get-name config-pair))
    (interactive)
    (do-stuff ,(config-get-name config-pair)))))
```